# Where is SQLite database stored in Windows phone 8.1

Tags: sqlite, windows-phone-8.1

I have a SQLite database in my Windows phone 8.1 application. I am copying it by using this code

```
 public async void UpDatabase()
 {
        bool isDatabaseExisting = false;

        try
        {
            StorageFile storageFile = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.GetFileAsync("ComplainSys.db");
            isDatabaseExisting = true;
        }
        catch
        {
            isDatabaseExisting = false;
        }

        if (!isDatabaseExisting)
        {
            StorageFile databaseFile = await Package.Current.InstalledLocation.GetFileAsync("ComplainSys.db");
            await databaseFile.CopyAsync(ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder);
        }
    }
```

I want to access that location where it is stored . When I put breakpoint and check that path and try to access that it shown this error.

[image]
[image]

How do I access that?

Answer (score 0):

`ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder` is the folder. But I don't really know how did you try to access the folder using the breakpoint, are you using Windows Explorer to open that folder? The path is local to phone storage, not your computer's one.

Comment: @user3814490 you can't use your computer's explorer to open that folder. In order to access it you need to use WinRT API or try using Isolated Storage Explore, but I'm not sure if it will work for WinRT.

Comment: @user3814490 Yes, Isolated Storage Explorer will work with WinRT apps, also you may take a look at Isolated Storage Spy.

Answer (score 0):

I use the other software, i think it's more good than isolated storage and don't need add external classes or same in your project... I used this: http://isostorespy.codeplex.com/downloads/get/835310

Just unzip folder and open your emulator, when emulator is opened, execute .exe and select your emulator, then u can explore local ,roaming and temp folder. Finally this software work with windows phone 8+ (8,8.1). It's too easy!

PD: If u had problems advise me, Good Luck!